# One Code, Two Different Compilations (One Dirty Version of BitCoin)

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, miner-configuration, bitcoin-cash, compiling

Right now i'm developing an AltCoin based on BitCoin Cash.

I have one code, which i compiled in two different servers (A and B).

The A server, compiles the Bitcoin as "Bitcoin ABC version v0.16.3.0--g2vdf00a68", but the B server compiles the Bitcoin as "Bitcoin ABC version v0.16.3.0--dirty".

[image]

Right now the nodes are visible as peers, between the servers. 
But the mining has been impossible.

I think it may be related with the difference between versions, on the compilation of the SAME CODE.

Here it's the compilation output of the dirty version:

https://pastebin.com/P8A2Ydk3

Answer (score 2):

Dirty means that the compiled binary includes code that is not committed in git. You can use the `git diff` command to see what the uncommitted code is and use `git show` to see what the  most recent commit is for each of your code trees. There's a good chance that what you think is the same code is not actually the same code.